# VirtualBox 4.1.20 (Windows 7 / Ubuntu 12.04 (32 bit)) copy/paste is broken

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, clipboard

I have a Windows 7 Pro host, and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS guest. I cannot get the shared clipboard working.

I have installed Guest Additions 4.1.20 on VirtualBox 4.1.20, have restarted, followed instructions found  [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp18411760), and have enabled bidirectional clipboard sharing within VirtualBox options.

However, I still cannot copy and paste between the host and guest. Copy/paste works great within the host, and within the guest, but not between the two.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: 4.1.18 had a bug about this... i updated to 4.1.20 and everything works fine.. have you enabled it in the host settings for the virtual machine?

Comment: Yeah within the virtual machine's settings, I set the clipboard sharing to bidrectional. Is there more to it?

Comment: ..only to install the VBoxGuestAdditions.. maybe reinstall it.. but its just a guess

Comment: @Cadbury yeah that might work, install the latest version of the Guest Additions (4.1.22)